# How Do I Modify the "ylabel" Property of a Catplot Graph When it is Part of a Subplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, subplot

I am trying to modify the `ylabel` property of 2 seaborn graphs in a subplot. However, using the `set_ylabel()` function on each axes does nothing.

I can't work directly with the `FacetGrid` as for some reason it doesn't work with the subplot (it draws additional empty grids, which is why I am calling `close()` after each draw).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns

fig_a, ax_a = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (16, 8))

fig_a.suptitle("Frequency of Exercise by Age")

ax_a[0].set_ylim([0, 500])
ax_a[0].set(ylabel = "Ylabel Test 1")
ax_a[0].set_title("Males (" + str(len(male_age_data)) + "/" + str(len(age_data)) + ")")

ax_a[1].set_ylim([0, 500])
ax_a[1].set_ylabel("Ylabel Test 2")
ax_a[1].set_title("Females (" + str(len(female_age_data)) + "/" + str(len(age_data)) + ")")

sns.catplot(x = "Active", hue = "Age", data = male_age_data, kind = "count", order = ["Inactive", "Active", "Very Active"], hue_order = ["<= 20", "21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51-60", "61-70", "71-80"], ax = ax_a[0])

plt.close()

sns.catplot(x = "Active", hue = "Age", data = female_age_data, kind = "count", order = ["Inactive", "Active", "Very Active"], hue_order = ["<= 20", "21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51-60", "61-70", "71-80"], ax = ax_a[1])

plt.close()
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTQTi.png), as you can see the y-label is still the default "count".

Setting the title on the axes works fine, I am curious as to why it doesn't affect the y-label and how I can work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that catplot overwrites the ylabel. Try moving your ylabel commands after the catplot commands.

I was able to reproduce your problem and fix it by changing the order of the commands that way.